# python dictionary formatted printout

Tags: python, dictionary, format, key

I'm trying to print a dictionary with two values for each key in a formatted way, where the keys are separated from the values and the without any brackets or comas just plane text indented, e.g.:

> --- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER ---
>
> Number__________Name_________________Address
>
> 1__________Google Scholar______________website1

instead of:

> --- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER ---
>
> Number___________Name_________________Address
>
> _ _
>
> 1 ('Google Scholar', 'website1')

here is my code:

```
web_pages = {1:('Google Scholar','website1'),
         2:('Moodle','website2'),
         3:('BBC','website3'),
         4:('Webmail','website4')}

##-------output_structure_top---------------------------
def output_structure_top ():
    print "--- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER --- "+"\n"  
    print "Number"+" "*10 +"Name"+" "*30+"Address \n"
    print "-"*60+"\n"

##----output_structure_bottom------------------------
def output_structure_bottom():
    print "-"*60+"\n"

##----------------------------------------------------

output_structure_top ()
for key, value in web_pages.iteritems():
    print key, value
output_structure_bottom()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
web_pages = {1:('Google Scholar','website1'),
         2:('Moodle','website2'),
         3:('BBC','website3'),
         4:('Webmail','website4')}

##-------output_structure_top---------------------------
def output_structure_top ():
    print "--- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER --- "+"\n"  
    print "Number"+" "*10 +"Name"+" "*30+"Address \n"
    print "-"*60+"\n"

##----output_structure_bottom------------------------
def output_structure_bottom():
    print "-"*60+"\n"

##----------------------------------------------------
def output_structure_value(key,value):
    print (str(key) +" "*10+ value[0] +" "*30 +value[1])


output_structure_top ()
for key, value in web_pages.iteritems():
    output_structure_value(key,value)
output_structure_bottom()
```